# How to bind to function that takes function as parameter

Tags: javascript

I have the following I want to pass a parameter from a higher context which is onDeselectionStyle to the eachlayer method.

```
clearAll: function(){
        this.map.eachLayer(function(layer){
            if(layer.options.clicked == true){
                layer.options.clicked == false;
                layer.setStyle(this.onDeselectionStyle);
            }
        })
    }
```

I know that I need to bind this to the function but I don't know how to do it in this format.
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1**

You can use the prototypical bind method on the function declaration:

```
clearAll: function () {
    this.map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        if (layer.options.clicked == true) {
            layer.options.clicked == false;
            layer.setStyle(this.onDeselectionStyle);
        }
    }.bind(this))
}
```

**Option 2**

If you are using ES6, you can use an arrow function which will use the parent scope:

```
clearAll: function () {
    this.map.eachLayer(layer => {
        if (layer.options.clicked == true) {
            layer.options.clicked == false;
            layer.setStyle(this.onDeselectionStyle);
        }
    })
}
```

**Option 3**

This one doesn't really have much to do with binding context, but you can store the scope in an accessible variable you can use later:

```
clearAll: function () {
    var that = this;
    this.map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        if (layer.options.clicked == true) {
            layer.options.clicked == false;
            layer.setStyle(that.onDeselectionStyle);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: The one I like is `that = this` option..  Maybe you could add as option 3.

Comment: @Keith "that" refers to the higher context ?

Comment: @zahma  Yes, you can use this technique to capture from any context.  It's kind of why I like it, rather than arrow functions it's more specific and less complicated than bind.

Comment: @Keith yah seems awsome and easier I'll try it (y) thank you